# How to write a query to find all tables in a db that have a specific column name? HIVE

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I've got a database with about 400 tables and I need to find all the tables searching by the column names. Basically I need something like:

```
select <tables> from <database> where table.columnName='tv';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. Hive metadata is *not* exposed through "system views", or an INFORMATION_SCHEMA, or anything that can be manipulated via SQL. All you can do is write a kind a shell script that executes a series of SHOW queries via `hive` or `beeline` or `hcat`, parses the text output, generates new SHOW queries, etc.

Comment: The alternative is the Java Metastore API, cf. http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.1.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html

Answer (score 0):

below shell script will give you desired result:

```
output=""|
hive -e 'show tables in <database_name>'  |
while read line
do
 echo "TABLE NAME : $line"
  if eval "hive -e 'describe <database_name>.$line'" | grep -q "tv"; then
     output+="Required table name: $line"'\n'
   else
     output+=""
  fi
echo -e "$output"
done
```